# how can launcher icon image name in mobile flex project using eclipse indigo?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder4.5

I am building an  mobile flex app in eclipse indigo  and have my app worked almost to completion and about ready for deployment. Unfortunately, I cannot find how to change the app icon and title for the system to read, so my app still shows up as Main with the default package symbol in the launcher. Does anyone know where to apply changes to these properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are properties in your app-config file.  If you main application file is Main.mxml; then most likely your app config is named Main-app.xml.  Look for the icon tag to specify the app icon.  One of my apps uses something like this:

```
<icon>
    <image32x32>/assets/icon/Icon32x32.png</image32x32>
    <image36x36>/assets/icon/Icon36x36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>/assets/icon/Icon48x48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>/assets/icon/Icon72x72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>/assets/icon/Icon114x114.png</image114x114>
</icon>
```

I believe the name under the icon is specified using the name parameter in the same file:

```
<name>My App Name</name>
```